# React Router Go to Previous Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement a 'go back' a step button but for whatever reason it keeps returning a 404 page not found error when doing so. It appears to only work when going to step 2 and going back to the first step (or default route)..

**Route Setup:**

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path='/onboard/' component={Main} />
    <Route path='/onboard/step2' component={Step2} />
    <Route path='/onboard/step3' component={Step3} />
    <Route path='/onboard/summary' component={Summary} />
</Router>
```

**Go Back Function:**

```
const handleBack = () => {
    props.history.go(-1);
};
```

Also, being that it's a "nested url" (so to speak), is it necessary to add the following to my onSubmit for Step2 or is there an alternative way of doing so?

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    action(data);
    props.history.push('./onboard/step2');
};
```

Everything following the second step seems to work with:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    action(data);
    props.history.push('./summary');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

if you `console.log('history', history)` you should see an `goBack()` method that you can call

EDIT: this is how you use it `props.history.goBack()` add that to a button
`<button onClick={()=> props.history.goBack()}>go back</button>`

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-forked-zecro?file=/src/Step2.js:868-890)

Comment: Even using goBack() i still get a 404 error page not found and I can't seem to figure out why...

Comment: that works for me. are you using browserHistory? or hash ?

Comment: I'm using the exact same thing as the following: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-gxvvc